# ios how to access the delegatee

Tags: ios, delegates

Say that `self` is the object `myObject` and I do something like `[self setDelegate:theDelegate]`

From inside `theDelegate` how can I access `myObject` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Delegate doesn't need to know about objects it's delegating. Most of delegate methods have a parameter that holds a pointer to instance which called the delegate, in case delegate needs to interact with the delegated object upon receiving a message from it. That's all you should ever do.

Example - change a background color of `UITextField` instance when it's done with editing:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // textField is a pointer to an instance that called us (the delegate)
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```